# MySQL: What happens to stored procedures, functions and triggers when dumping complete database with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have been using `mysqldump` for backup purposes.
We have a new database here with lots of functions, procedures and triggers. What happens to these functions or procedures or triggers if I take a complete database backup?

Will these triggers, functions and procedures also be dumped?
Are there any precautions need to be taken in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> mysqldump will backup by default all the triggers but NOT the stored
>   procedures/functions. There are 2 mysqldump parameters that control
>   this behavior:
>
> ```
> –routines (procedures and functions) – false by default
> –triggers – true by default
> ```

http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/

Comment: For more information see the mysqldump documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I added the --routines option to command line, but stored functions/procedures are still missing in the backup. Do I have to backup them manually copying their content one by one? Why this option is missing. It's a very big mess!

Comment: Add --events to backup events too